# What's the best way to visualize sequence of events within pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have a dataframe showing sequence of events per session on weblog data, looking like this

```
SessionID     EventSequence   UrlPath
00001           1              Login
00001           2              Overview
00001           3              Account   
00001           4              LogOff
00002           1              Login
00002           2              LogOff
00003           1              Login
00003           2              Account
00003           3              Overview
00003           4              Overview 
00003           5              LogOff
....
```

I want to visualize this data in the most efficient, user-friendly way to show the most common paths within sessions in general (thinking of the tree mainly, but can be something else). What would be the most optimal way to visualize sequence of events within data? Can you please share any examples in different domains?

Comment: What if you try with a sankey diagram? https://github.com/ricklupton/floweaver

Comment: Perhaps you could use a directed graph where the edge width corresponds to the frequency of the transition.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best fine here:
Stacked Bar Graph:
[image]

from [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html)

Or

3D bar charts
[image]

from [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html)

In case you looking for common traffic you can you:
[image]
Sankey Diagram like [here](https://plot.ly/python/sankey-diagram/)

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about it, but it only shows distribution of particular events per event sequence. Not really the paths most users are taking.